# Como atribuir numero ao nome enum TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

Tudo bem pessoal ? 
Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema no TypeScript 2.3.

Problema: Meu back-end  me envia uma propriedade no Json com valor 00 ou 01,
eu preciso converter para Regular ou Extra.
Porém não consigo atribuir números no nome do Enum, já tentei fazer um switch dentro do método get mas nada funcionou, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
export class Viagem {   tipoViagem: string;   descViagem: string;

  public get $descViagem(): string {
    switch (this.tipoViagem) {
      case "00":
        return "REGULAR";

      case "01":
        return "EXTRA";
    }   } }
```

Comment: Pode postar o Switch que você  fez?

Comment: @LucasBrogni, claro, adicionado.

Comment: Onde está o `enum`?

Comment: O enum eu não consigo criar, pois não posso adicionar nomes como 00 e 01

Comment: @VictorOliveira Acredito que o problema é que você não está dando um break; no case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class Viagem {   
    tipoViagem: string;    
    descViagem: string;

  public get $descViagem(): string {
    if (this.tipoViagem == "00") {
        return "REGULAR";
     }
     else
     if (this.tipoViagem == "01"){
        return "EXTRA";
     }
     else{
        return "ERRO";
     }   
} 
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante comentar sobre o que está ocorrendo para o entendimento do colega.